# Error in graphql schema running in magento 2 : Cannot query field \"wordoftheday\" on type \"Wordoftheday\"."?

Tags: custom, magento2.3.2, graphql

I created a custom module with a custom table in **magento 2.3.2** including **grpahql schema**.

**I want to get the data using graphql by passing an argument.**

I am getting the following error in **Alatair GrapgQL client** chrome extension.

> {
>     "errors": [
>       {
>         "message": "Cannot query field \"wordoftheday\" on type \"Wordoftheday\".",
>         "category": "graphql",
>         "locations": [
>           {
>             "line": 3,
>             "column": 5
>           }
>         ]
>       }
>     ]
>   }

I passed the query like below.

```
{
wordoftheday ( id : 1) {
Wordoftheday{
  word
  verb
  meaning
  detail
}
}
}
```

> /app/code/Ayakil/Wordoftheday/etc/schema.graphqls

```
type Query {
wordoftheday (
    id: Int @doc(description: "Current Day to show WOD in Home page")
): Wordoftheday @resolver(class: "Ayakil\\Wordoftheday\\Model\\Resolver\\Wordoftheday") @doc(description: "The Sales Order query returns information about customer all placed order")
}
type Wordoftheday @doc(description: "wod information") {
word : String  @doc(description: "word")
verb : String  @doc(description: "verb")
meaning : String  @doc(description: "meaning")
detail : String  @doc(description: "detail")
}
```

> /app/code/Ayakil/Wordoftheday/Model/Resolver/DataProvider/Wordoftheday.php

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\Wordoftheday\Model\Resolver\DataProvider;
class Wordoftheday
{
protected $_wordofthedayFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Ayakil\Wordoftheday\Model\WordofthedayFactory $wordofthedayFactory
)
{
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->_wordofthedayFactory  = $wordofthedayFactory;
}

public function getWordoftheday( int $date_to_show)
{
    try {
        /* filter for all customer orders */
        //$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('id', $date_to_show,'eq')->create();
        $wod = $this->_wordofthedayFactory->create();
        $collection = $wod->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('id',$date_to_show);

    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(__($e->getMessage()), $e);
    }
    return $collection;
}
}
```

What is my mistake here?please help me to short it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found my mistake.
My error was capturing the id in the resolver file.

```
private function getId(array $args): int
{
    if (!isset($args['id'])) {
        throw new GraphQlInputException(__('"id should be specified'));
    }

    return (int)$args['id'];
}
```

**$args['id']** here as per my graphQl schema I want to pass id, but I passed something else.

And also my passed query also wrong.
I should pass like below to get the result as per my graphql schema.

```
query wordoftheday {
wordoftheday( id : 5){
    word
    verb
    meaning
    details
  }
}
```

I correct all my mistakes and got it up and run, to get a clear understanding please read [How to create a Graphql schema by passing an argument for custom Magento 2 module with the custom table?](http://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-create-a-graphql-schema-by-passing-argument-for-custom-magento-2-module-with-custom-table/).